# Use NotificationCenter to add Observer in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notificationcenter

I understand that the NotificationCenter has changed, and I have looked up how to change it to the new implementation, using this link:  [NotificationCenter issue on Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204703/notificationcenter-issue-on-swift-3), but i still cannot get mine to work! I am doing an assignment from my class using the class text book and this is my class so far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Persistence
//
//  Created by Skyleguy on 10/31/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Skyleguy. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var lineFields: [UITextField]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filePath = self.dataFilePath()
        if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath))
        {
            let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) as! [String]
            for i in 0 ..< array.count
            {
                lineFields[i].text = array[i]
            }
        }

        let notificationName = Notification.Name("applicationWillResignActive")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Persistence.applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification)), name: notificationName, object: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        let filePath = self.dataFilePath()
        let array = (self.lineFields as NSArray).value(forKey: "text") as! NSArray
        array.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

after all of this I am still getting an error:

"Module "Persistence" has no member named 'applicationWillResignActive'"

please help!

Comment: "I understand that the NotificationCenter has changed" Then you understand wrong. It hasn't changed at all.

Answer (score 5):

First off, this line is wrong:

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("applicationWillResignActive")
```

The whole point of having Notification.Name is that you use the existing *constant*, which is `.UIApplicationWillResignActive`.

Second, your whole expression `Persistence.applicationWillResignActive(...)` is nonsense. That is not [how you form a function reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/341994) for `#selector`. This function is part of `self`, so just use the function name pure and simple.

So, like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
    selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive), 
    name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, 
    object: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your notification is incorrectly named, in Swift 3 this has changed to the following:

```
NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive
```

That will give you the correct name for your observer.

Another thing is your selector is incorrect, please try the following:

```
#selector(ViewController.applicationWillResignActive(notification:))
```

Comment: Both things you said are wrong. The whole point is that you _don't_ have to say `Notification.Name` because Swift knows that this _is_ a `Notification.Name`. And your `#selector` is no more legal as a function reference than the OP's; it appears to be more of a function declaration.

Comment: @matt I agree, however it is not wrong to write `Notification.Name` either. With the selector I believe it must include `(Notification:)` as the function declaration states so.

Comment: Then you believe wrong, and in any case that is not what you wrote in your answer. What you have wont compile. That is not a matter of opinion or belief.

Comment: @Wink your answer isn't wrong but it is not following convention and not harnessing the implicit type resolution of Swift