# AVAudiosessionInterruptionNotification in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift2

This is the code I had in swift 2.

How do I use the same thing in swift 3?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "handleInterruption", name: AVAudiosessionInterruptionNotification, object: nil)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615219/4063602)

As it says:

> All of the system notification types are now defined as static constants on Notification.Name; i.e. .UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching, .UITextFieldTextDidChange, etc.

So, in your case, you are probably looking for `Notification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption`

And I think this should work for you:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption), name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)
```

Hope that helps.