# Swift - UNUsernotification checking changes in BadgeNumberIcon

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I Would like to display the value of the badge number in a label.

So far i've put everything in my viewWillAppear. So every time the controller is loaded the variable is assigned. Here's the code:

```
var deliveredNotif = Int()

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
deliveredNotif = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
myBadgeLabel.text = "\(deliveredNotif)"
}
```

My question is:
How can i update deliveredNotif if the controller is active and so viewWillAppear is already been called? Meaning if I am in the controller is there a way to trigger a func which will update the value of deliveredNotif every time the value of applicationIconBadgeNumber is changed?

Thank you!

-------UPDATE----MY SOLUTION
I created a constant variable:
var iconBadgeNumber = NSNumber()

in my Appdelegate i have:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge])
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "applicationIconBadgeNumber"), object: nil)
    iconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber
}
```

and then in my controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateIconBadgeNumber), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "applicationIconBadgeNumber"), object: nil)


}

@objc func updateIconBadgeNumber() {
    if iconBadgeNumber == 0 {
        print("zero")
    } else {
    print("there unread notification")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your `UIViewController` as an observer for the key path "applicationIconBadgeNumber":

First register for remote notifications. In your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, add:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { _, _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
```

don't forget to add also: `import UserNotifications` on the top of your file

Then add in your viewDidLoad:

```
UIApplication.shared.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "applicationIconBadgeNumber", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Then, override the observeValue function:

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                                        of object: Any?,
                                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                                          context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "applicationIconBadgeNumber" {
            deliveredNotif = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
            myBadgeLabel.text = "\(deliveredNotif)"
        }
    }
```

Comment: i've tried to do exactly what you have suggested... but when if the UIViewController is already opened it doesn't trigger the observeValue...

Comment: I updated my answer: I added the register first. I have tested in a sample project and it works ;)

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 13 / Swift 5. The callback is triggered only when setting `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` manually, but not when a push notification is received

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different ways in order to notify an object about a changed value :

- First of all you have the Notification center in order to notify an observer when your value changed.
  Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204703/notificationcenter-issue-on-swift-3), and more informations on the Internet, you will find what you want.
- Moreover, you can also use protocol and delegate but it seems kind of heavy for just a notification update on a value.
- Finally You should definitely look around this [post](https://cocoacasts.com/key-value-observing-kvo-and-swift-3/), it explains the principle of the Key-Value Observing (KVO), I am sure you already heard about it.

And to conclude, the ultimate article, will explain you when you should use each of this principle.

[KVO vs NSNotification vs protocol/delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864838/kvo-vs-nsnotification-vs-protocol-delegates)

You should try to investigate more seriously before posting a question that is already answered multiple times.

Hope this articles will help you.

Comment: Thx for the answer... i'm new to swift... and i've done some research... unfortunately haven't find my answer... i thought about using Notificationcenter... and it is what i'm trying to do. My issue is that unfortunately to me is not very clear where to put the observer...